# How I can do this ? Adding exaplanations between sections (of cells)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, footer

I want to add explanation between cells.

I'm experimenting with sections, trying to make the cell opaque, without borders, ... but sure it exists a better approach ...

thanks,

m.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are after here. Are you looking for a tableview with sections and text between the sections? Or are you looking for a tableview with a cell that has "main text" and then some detail text in a row below  (but within the same cell)?

Comment: Image now clarifies, thanks. Brandon Bodnar has the answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UITableViewDataSource` protocol has two methods of use to you

```
- tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:titleForFooterInSection:
```

You can use these to add headers and footers around each section to provide description text.

In `UITableViewDelegate` you can also modify the views for the headers and footers with

```
– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement this method in your UITableViewDataSource object

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

It allows you to pass back a UIView to be displayed in the header for any given section.

Comment: I've implemented the viewForHeaderInSection in some apps, now that you mention it, it can be a possibility, I don't know where I have my head today ... thanks